# CAKEPHP Group by problem in paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

CAKEPHP Group by problem in paginate..

This is my table structure

```
 Friends Table
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user1_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',--> UserFrom
  `user2_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',---> UserTo
```

I need to get all the unique records of one user and his user1_id = 100

There are lot of duplicate values in user2_id. I need to get the unique values 
While i trying this code it returns only first 12 values(according to limit).
If i commented the group by line then all records are displaying (including duplicate values)

```
$this->paginate = array(
                    'conditions' => $conditions,
        'contain'=>array(
            'UserFrom'=>array(
                'fields'=>array(
                   'UserFrom.id',
                   'UserFrom.first_name',
                   'UserFrom.last_name',
                ),
             ),
             'UserTo'=>array(
                'fields'=>array(
                    'UserTo.id',
                    'UserTo.first_name',
                    'UserTo.last_name',
                    )
             )
            ),'limit' => 12,
            'order' => array('Friend.id' => 'desc'),
            'recursive'=>0,
            'fields'=>array('DISTINCT Friend.user2_id','Friend.*'),
            'group'=>array('UserTo.id'),
            );
```

This is my sql query on that page

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `friends` AS `Friend` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `UserTo` ON (`Friend`.`user2_id` = `UserTo`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `users` AS `UserFrom` ON (`Friend`.`user1_id` = `UserFrom`.`id`) WHERE `UserFrom`.`nick_name` = 'shyam' AND `Friend`.`status` = 'friend' GROUP BY `UserTo`.`id`

SELECT DISTINCT `Friend`.`user2_id`, `Friend`.*, `UserTo`.`id`, `UserTo`.`first_name`, `UserTo`.`last_name`, `UserTo`.`nick_name`, `UserTo`.`name`, `UserTo`.`icon_medium`, `UserTo`.`icon_big`, `UserFrom`.`id`, `UserFrom`.`first_name`, `UserFrom`.`last_name`, `UserFrom`.`nick_name`, `UserFrom`.`name` FROM `friends` AS `Friend` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `UserTo` ON (`Friend`.`user2_id` = `UserTo`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `users` AS `UserFrom` ON (`Friend`.`user1_id` = `UserFrom`.`id`) WHERE `UserFrom`.`nick_name` = 'shyam' AND `Friend`.`status` = 'friend' GROUP BY `UserTo`.`id` ORDER BY `Friend`.`id` desc LIMIT 12

1.First  count query returning count properly 
2.Second query if i put limit it not working properly. i.e there are 144 records in my table i need to display 12 per page.. only first page coming if i use group by and limit

Comment: You should add dump of SQL queries into question (`echo $this->element('sql_dump')` in your view)

Comment: yes added sql dump. please help me to find solution

Comment: "i need to display 12 per page.. only first page coming if i use group by and limit": I don't understand what problem are you having (??)

Comment: when i used group by and limit it displaying only first 12 records.. so pagination is not coming. i need a solution to get the unique records with pagination option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have either `DISTINCT` **or** `GROUP BY`, not both - they're duplicating each other and probably causing problems with your query. Remove one of them and retry.

**Note:** If you want to *manually* request pages other than 1st with `$this->paginate()`, add `'page'` parameter with page number to your `$this->paginate` array, like this:

```
$this->paginate = array_merge($this->paginate, array('page' => $pageNumber);
```

**However, normally you wouldn't want to do this**, as paginator does this automatically (passing `page` variable via URL parameter to your action) as long as you use pagination controls in your view (see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1233/Pagination-in-Views).